# Code:: Blocks missing keywords

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

I can not use **typeof** as well as **getchar_unlocked()** ( similarly, **putchar_unlocked()** ) on my system in the latest version of Code:: Blocks.
I use windows 8.1.

Is it possible to custom add these functionalities?

Are many more useful keywords not available in Code::Blocks?

If so, is there a similar IDE for C++ which doesn't lack such keywords?

Comment: getchar_unlocked() does not work on windows

Comment: It's not about the IDE, it's about the compiler and platform. `typeof` is a non-standard gcc extension and the functions you mention aren't available on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the IDE's fault. These keywords for C++ do not run on windows as they are not part of the gcc compiler you are using.

`getchar_unlocked` is not a C or C++ standard function and therefore it's no surprise that it doesn't work on Windows. It is a POSIX standard and Windows compilers don't support all POSIX functions.

If you replaced `getchar_unlocked` with `getchar`, it would work.

As for `typeof`, it is not not standard C++ either. Instead, you can use `decltype`

Also, `getchar_unlocked()` is not thread safe. I think you are speaking in the context of programming competitions. Here, 99.9% of the times, `printf` and `scanf` are fast enough. Instead of fast IO, focus on designing an efficient algorithm for the problem. `getchar_unlocked` should be used as a last resort.